# json convert javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I have json message in this format

```
{"id":21,"image":"binary64image","pdate":"2014-01-27"},
{"id":22,"image":"binary64image","pdate":"2014-01-27"},
{"id":21,"image":"binary64image","pdate":"2014-01-27"}
```

and I want to convert this into javascript array, I have tried

```
        var txt = '{ "potholes" : [' + data + ']}';
        var jsonObj = eval("(" + txt + ")");            
        alert(jsonObj.potholes[1].id);
```

and

```
        var potholes = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(potholes[1].id);
```

neither worked. The data is there as it is in a success to an ajax call which returns json object.

Comment: What is `console.log(data)`? An array? A string?

Comment: just in case you've not... have you tried: JSON.stringify(jsonObj) ?

Comment: Alert(data) overloads the messagebox on my android phone, but I have test from server from my webservice which returns application/json as above

Comment: The JSON is broken (unless you did not paste it completely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example work great!

simple data should be a string

```
data = '{id: ....'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VSDC7/1/

Comment: Yes it was working although I had square brackets round my data, which caused it to fail as the string already had these. I would have fixed this a lot sooner but I do not have a console as working on phonegap

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your JSON response in JavaScript array like below :

```
var data = '{"id":21,"image":"binary64image","pdate":"2014-01-27"},{"id":22,"image":"binary64image","pdate":"2014-01-27"},{"id":21,"image":"binary64image","pdate":"2014-01-27"}';
var result = eval("["+data+"]");  //convert your response into JavaScript array

for(var i in result) // read your array value
    alert("id : "+result[i].id+" --> image : "+result[i].image+" --> pdate : "+result[i].pdate);
```

[Fiddel Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pJcr4/)

Comment: `eval` is a bad way to parse json. You can read about it on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your input data to an array ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gZ53V/1/)):

```
var input = '{"id":21,"image":"binary64image","pdate":"2014-01-27"},{"id":22,"image":"binary64image","pdate":"2014-01-27"},{"id":21,"image":"binary64image","pdate":"2014-01-27"}',
    inputArr = '[' + input + ']',
    arr = JSON.parse(inputArr);
for (var i in arr)
    console.log(arr[i].id);
```